# ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/opt/homebrew/lib' while compiling C++

Tags: c++, macos, command-line, homebrew, zsh

I'm trying to run this sample C++ file but I get error from both VS Code Editor and while compiling it on zsh terminal in mac.

This is my sample C++ file

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int binarySearch(vector<int> numbers, int key)
{
    int start = 0;
    int end = numbers.size() - 1;
    int mid = start + (end - start) / 2;

    while (start <= end)
    {
        if (key == numbers.at(mid))
        {
            return key;
        }
        else if (key >= numbers.at(mid))
        {
            start = mid + 1;
        }
        else
        {
            end = mid - 1;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

int main()
{

    vector<int> numbers = {2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12};

    int requiredNumber = binarySearch(numbers, 8);

    cout << requiredNumber << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

VS Code gives me error of

```
error: non-aggregate type 'vector<int>' cannot be initialized with an initializer list
    vector<int> numbers = {2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12};
                ^         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

although my C++ version is `c++17`

While compiling it myself with command `g++ -std=c++17 main.cpp` or `g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp`, it gives out error of

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/opt/homebrew/lib'
```

I googled it and found here https://github.com/crystal-lang/shards/issues/49, but it is not relevant to what I'm doing right now, I think.

What is this error from terminal? I would be very grateful for helping me out with it.

Comment: You're missing at least 3 lines of code to get a functioning program, if that first snippet is indeed the entire contents of your file. Better is 2 lines and some extra typing.

Comment: It should be `std::vector<int>` (and `std::cout`, `std::endl`) and you're missing the necessary includes `#include <iostream>` and `#include <vector>`.

Comment: And a definition of `binarySearch()` now that I'm looking harder.

Comment: The homebrew error is interesting. Did you add brew's gcc to your PATH? You otherwise have to go out of your way to use brew g++.

Comment: Could you let me know how to add that to PATH?

When I did `echo $PATH` it showed `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin`, there is no brew gcc.

Comment: PSA: Unless you're manipulating the vector given, use a const ref (`const std::vector<...>&` which saves making a copy.

Comment: To add a directory to the PATH using zsh, do a `path+=/directory/to/add`. To add it in front of your PATH, do a `path=(/directory/to/add $path)`.